# iPhone internet sharing doesn't stay on

Tags: ios, internet-sharing

I activate internet sharing in control center in iOS 13 on iPhone 8, and connect to it using WiFi. A few minutes later my computer complains about no internet connection, so I return to control center to check on internet sharing: it's now disabled. This behavior repeats about every ten minutes if I persist.

I don't understand. What is the point of internet sharing if it won't stay on? Am I using it the wrong way?

Comment: Are you talking about a Personal Hotspot?

Comment: @DaniilManokhin Yes, most likely

Comment: Is power saving mode enabled? Does your iPhone have more than 20% of battery when it turns off?

Comment: @Lulucmy Power saving is off. It has more than 20% battery when it happens.